# GWT wrap <th/> element as Widget and adding click event

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I need adding a click event to th (in a table with UIBinder context). Is it possible? Have I to create a TH-Widget with a wrap method? If it's so, how?

Thanks,
Randomize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own widget the old-fashioned way with

```
class TableHead extends Widget implements HasClickHandlers
```

and then override onBrowserEvent and implement addClickHandler using other GWT widgets as a model. But I don't know how that interacts with UIBinder.